# Python raises an AttributeError when methods on the sklearn Pipeline object are called

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, attributeerror

### Problem

I am calling the `fit_transform()` and `transform()` methods on a `Pipeline` object, but Python is raising an AttributeError whenever I try to do so. Here is what I'm trying to run, with imports. (Note: train/test splitting has been done already)

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipe = Pipeline([('mean_impute', SimpleImputer()), 
                 ('norm',        StandardScaler()), 
                 ('sklearn_lm',  LinearRegression())])

pipe.fit_transform(x_train, y_train)  #<-- error here

x_transform = pipe.transform(x_test)  #<-- and here if previous line is absent
```

The text of the error is as follows:

`AttributeError: This 'Pipeline' has no attribute 'fit_transform'`

What went wrong? I'm sure it's something simple.

### Things I have tried:

- Looked over the documentation for sci-kit learn to confirm that [these methods exist for the Pipeline object in sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)
- Checked the sizes of `x_train` and `y_train` to make sure they were the same, and that they both had headers
- Reinstalled `sci-kit learn`

Comment: What version of sklearn are you using?

Comment: @John - I'm on 1.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for [`sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit_transform) states that it's "[o]nly valid if the final estimator either implements `fit_transform` or `fit` and `transform`." Wording may be a bit ambiguous, but it means two possibilities: (i) final estimator implements `fit_transform`, or (ii) final estimator implements `fit` and `transform`.

Your final estimator is [`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn-linear-model-linearregression), which implements `fit`, but not `transform`. This is why the error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

On [this website](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit_transform) it says that this method is only valid if the final estimator either implements fit_transform or fit and transform. I do not know what a final estimator is, but that might be your problem (I know this wasn't very helpful but I tried).